# React-Typist 2.0.5 incompatible with React 18.2.0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, windows, npm-install, next.js13

I'm building my portfolio using Next and typescript (latest version)

I have react 18.2.0 installed, but react-typist 2.0.5 seems to want a downgraded version of react. However I am using 18.2.0 functionalities. Anyway to resolve this?

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-typist@2.0.5
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.11.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.11.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/system, @mui/styled-engine)
npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/material, @mui/system, @mui/styled-engine)
npm ERR!   27 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0 || ^16.0" from react-typist@2.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typist
npm ERR!   react-typist@"^2.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14 || ^15.0 || ^16.0" from react-typist@2.0.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typist
npm ERR!     react-typist@"^2.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried `--force and --legacy-peer-deps` which allows the installation but the actual runtime will fail. I also tried asking chatgpt to see if I was missing a small detail. I believe I am utilizing the latest versions correctly ie
import React, `{Component}` from `react`;
import Typist from 'react-typist';
But the error persists.